Bevel behavior in unexpected (even after adjusting normals)
I am trying to follow this tutorial to create a roman column (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy0Bd0_CCrk&t=92s)
However, I am having problems with beveling the edges of the top and bottom of the top cylinder.
I checked the normals and applied the scale as recommended in various posts but still issues with the lower edges of the top cylinder. when i increase the angle (say 4 or 5 degrees, the shape becomes unexpected. I tried to flip the normals of the bottom of the top cylinder but still the same.
I am using macos, blender 4.1.1
After the bevel of the top cylinder. Expectation is a smooth curved surface like the bottom

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?
thanks
Mourad


I've just done that tutorial in Blender 4.1.1 (albeit using Windows) and it worked exactly as described so all I can suggest is that you start the tutorial again following each step exactly. If you still have problems I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Maybe share your blendfile. If you're restarting the tutorial you'd probably avoid tthe problem. But still if you're sharing your file, we may spot the problem so you get to know what else to look for, if a problem like this occurs again :)

The only thing I can find with your file is that you've extruded the column up by 4" instead of 2" as specified in the tutorial. You also have Proportional Editing turned on. Hit the 'O' (O not Zero) key to turn it off. After I corrected those I could carry on with the tutorial without problem. I've no idea how you managed to get the shape you show in your image though!

You have quite a lot of duplicate vertices, i'd suggest you merge them by selecting all and M>By Distance

thank you both.... the issue was i was not extruding the upper cylinder before beveling.
Once I did that it worked well,
We can close this now.

@NiklasFriedrichs That's from the bevelling where they were set to overlap. It's mentioned later in the tutorial.
